# Firebase Hosting + Cloud Functions + node.js problem

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I use node.js with Firebase Hosting, and Functions also.
I try to set up a basic function but deploying send error message, according to debug:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Also:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>
GET 1603621088 /gcf-upload-us-central1-9fe5e3ed-4073-4e5c-a9ef-a8ad975ad259/0d0b6145-1eb5-4dad-b5cb-a550dcd968a0.zip
</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

My index.js in function folder is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("<<path to file under Functions dir, downloaded from Firebase Console/Settings/Service accounts/Generate new private key>>");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://MYPROJECT.firebaseio.com"
});
    
exports.urbData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
})
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "MYPROJECT",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\xxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxx",

"key": "<<API KEY>>",

  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I have checked Google Cloud Console, and Google Cloud Functions is enabled to the API key. (I also double-checked the firebase init enabled Functions.)

I am not sure that it is important, but actually I have another app (Android) in the same project.

Does anybody know the solution to correct the error?

Comment: Hi @SzB this error usually indicates that either you are not setting the service account for the deploy correctly or this service account doesn't have the proper permissions. Considering that, could you please follow-up this tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/understanding-oauth2-and-deploy-a-basic-auth-srv-to-cloud-functions) and check if it helps you?

Comment: Thank you very much @gso_gabriel, I have double-checked the procedure of the tutorial and everything seems to be OK, though the site still gives the error mentioned. Any other idea?

Comment: Hi @SzB if everything is set as in the tutorial, I would recommend you to reach out to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly, so they can assist you directly with this issue.

Comment: Finally I have found the mistake, I had made earlier. It was a SERVICE that I have set, so I had to unset it, to have only the valid service. 'functions:config:unset SERVICE' command did the trick.